# Java 8, While Loop: Reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one

Tags: java, visual-studio, while-loop, break

I've got a class which contains the following:

```
while (true) {
            // if minimum element in the queue is greater than required sweetness
            // then we are done
            if (queue.peek() >= minSweetness) {
                solutionPossible = true;
                break;
            } else {
                // if there are more than or equal to 2 elements,
                // then only solution is possible
                // because we have already checked queue.peek() for the single element
                // present, and that is less than minSweetness
                if (queue.size() >= 2) {
                    // remove minimum and 2nd minimum values
                    int a1 = queue.poll();
                    int a2 = queue.poll();

                    // again push the value to the queue
                    // after calculating the combined sweetness
                    queue.offer(a1 + 2 * a2);
                } else {
                    // for single element that is less than required sweetness
                    // no solution is possible
                    solutionPossible = false;
                    break;
                }
                // increase total number of operations
                operations++;
            }
        }
```

> 

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

VScode tells me to reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one,
so I am not as experienced as to what other method I can think of, I tried to used quick fix and It didn't work,
anybody has any idea how to write this class differently...?

I tried to use quick fix and it didn't show other options though...

Comment: You can do `Boolean solutionPossible = null; do { ... } while (solutionPossible == null)`. Or you can move the whole thing to a separate method and `return false;` or `return true;` from within the loop.

Comment: I see no `continue` and only 2 `break`.  So, you only have to eliminate one.

Comment: Noticing that you have `while (true)`, one way to reduce number of `break` is to use a loop control variable:  `boolean decided = false; while ( ! decided) { if (queue.peek() >= minSweetness) {   solutionPossible = true; decided = true; } else { ` ...

Comment: Note that you don't need an `else` after `break;`.

Comment: I am sorry, can you write the code down so I get exactly what you, Kinda confused though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of coding the `while` as an infinite loop, and `break`ing out of it, use a variable to control loop continuation or exit. In this case, I chose a `boolean`:

```
boolean decided = false;
while ( ! decided ) {
            // if a minimum element in the queue is 
            // greater than the required sweetness
            // then we are done
            if (queue.peek() >= minSweetness) {
                solutionPossible = true;
                decided = true;
            } else {
                // if there are more than or equal to 2 elements,
                // then only solution is possible
                // because we have already checked 
                // queue.peek() for the single element
                // present, and that is less than minSweetness
                if (queue.size() >= 2) {
                    // remove minimum and 2nd minimum values
                    int a1 = queue.poll();
                    int a2 = queue.poll();

                    // again push the value to the queue
                    // after calculating the combined sweetness
                    queue.offer(a1 + 2 * a2);
                } else {
                    // for a single element that is 
                    // less than the required sweetness
                    // no solution is possible
                    solutionPossible = false;
                    decided = true;                       
                }
                // increase the total number of operations
                operations++;
            }
        }
```

By the way, I like retaining the first `break`. It's a style  preference:

```
boolean decided = false;
while ( ! decided ) {
            // if a minimum element in the queue is 
            // greater than the required sweetness
            // then we are done
            if (queue.peek() >= minSweetness) {
                solutionPossible = true;
                decided = true;
                break;

            
                // if there are more than or equal to 2 elements,
                // then only solution is possible
                // because we have already checked 
                // queue.peek() for the single element
                // present, and that is less than minSweetness
                if (queue.size() >= 2) {
                ...
```

Retaining the first `break` allows elimination of the first `else`, reducing the nesting level by one for the code that follows.

Comment: Oh, that work, I couldn't do it any other way since I have to follow every rules given to us though... #collegelifesuck

Comment: Well, "Reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one" is advice, not a requirement. You are free to ignore the advice, especially if ignoring it pleases your professor.

Comment: You are sure right, thanks though...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to preserve the original structure of the loop (i.e. `while (true)` ) then this is one method of complexity reduction (comments removed):

```
while (true)
{
    if (queue.peek() >= minSweetness || queue.size() < 2) {
        solutionPossible = (queue.peek() >= minSweetness);
        break;
    }
    int a1 = queue.poll();
    int a2 = queue.poll();

    queue.offer(a1 + 2 * a2);
    operations++;
}
```

The two loop "breaks" are condensed into one.  The difference in their processing is the setting of the `solutionPossible` which can be set based on the first condition.

The `else` is removed as unnecessary.

If `peek` were a costly operation (which it likely is not) then assigning the result to variable first would be an optimization since it is used twice.